# Create clientside dateTime histogram

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, charts, histogram

I would like to display an histogram of a dateTime array.

```
var data = {
    '2015-04-02 11:23:05',
    '2015-05-03 11:20:05',
    '2015-05-04 15:20:55',
    '2015-07-05 13:27:15',
    '2015-07-05 11:20:05',
    '2015-08-04 11:21:05',
    '2015-08-06 17:40:05',
    '2015-08-06 11:20:09',
    '2015-09-02 14:21:05',
    '2015-09-06 11:20:55',
    '2016-02-04 17:27:13',
    '2016-02-07 11:20:05'
};
```

I used to work with GoogleChart, but apparently dates are not supported yet.

What JS chart library do you advise ? I would like to have full control on the style of the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researchs, I have decided to use GoogleChart library.

As all the other libraries I have found, It does not handle DateTime histogram.

Therefore, I had to develop some functions to compute a DateTime histogram and display it with the other charts available (typically `ColumChart`).

Here are my functions:

```
var createDateTimeHistogram = function(data, timeAggregation, key, min, max)
{
    if(data && data.length)
    {
        var dateTimeHistogram = [];

        var minData = +Infinity;
        var maxData = -Infinity;

        /* Initialization */

        var dateTimes = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            if(data[i][key])
            {
                var value = getDateObjectFromDateTime(data[i][key]).getTime();

                dateTimes.push(value);

                minData = Math.min(minData, value);
                maxData = Math.max(maxData, value);
            }
        }

        min = (min) ? getDateObjectFromDateTime(min).getTime() : minData;
        max = (max) ? getDateObjectFromDateTime(max).getTime() : maxData;

        var interval = timeAggregation * 60 * 1000; //Conversion m -> ms

        var numberOfBeans = (max !== min) ? (1 + ((max - min) / interval)) : 100;

        /** Check **/

        var numberOfBeansMax = 1000;

        numberOfBeans = Math.min(numberOfBeansMax, numberOfBeans);

        interval = (max - min) / (numberOfBeans - 1);

        /* Create dateTimeHistogram array */

        for(var j = 0; j < numberOfBeans; j++)
        {
            dateTimeHistogram[j] = {
                dateTime: new Date(min + (j + 0.5) * interval),
                count: 0
            };
        }

        /* Count */

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var beanNumber = Math.floor((dateTimes[i] - min) / interval);

            dateTimeHistogram[beanNumber].count += 1;
        }

        /* Return */

        return dateTimeHistogram;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
};

var getDateObjectFromDateTime = function(dateTime)
{
    if(dateTime)
    {
        var t = dateTime.split(/[- :]/);
        return new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following:

- [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/)
- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
- [Chartist](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/)
- [Flot for jQuery](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

I have used ChartJS and Highcharts - the latter is extremely full featured and gives a lot of control. Have also used [Harry Plotter](https://github.com/nikopol/Harry-Plotter) which is really lightweight and easy to use, but doesn't provide a great deal of styling control.

Comment: 1+ For Harry Plotter! ChartJS is the easiest one I have used though. Great list.